# 503 RequestThrottled : Amazon Product Advertising API CartCreate

Tags: amazon-product-api

I am using scratchpad to explore this api. I am able to use item search and item lookup however I have not been able to successfully use cartCreate a single time. I am getting this error:-

Do i need to ask for a special permission to use cartCreate ?

```
Error! RequestThrottled
HTTP Status 503: Service Unavailable
AWS Access Key ID: __my_key___. You are submitting requests too quickly. Please retry your requests at a slower rate.
```

PS: So far I have only generated few sales from my affiliate account and signed up for this api. Could that be a reason for this throttling? Is there any developer account which is not subject to such throttling so that I can continue with the exploratory work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

CartCreate has been removed in the new API version. Instead, you have to create your own Add To Cart link or form:
https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/add-to-cart-form.html

In general, you'll want to minimize the number of requests you're making, as it's very easy to bump up against those throttling limits.

Source : https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=318920

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem :
I think you explore scratchpad from

https://webservices.amazon.fr/scratchpad/index.html#

with is the **old** API version

With your account (and mine) I get a disturbing error message : HTTP Status 503

You should use the new scratchpad version for the **API 5** of Amazon Product Advertising :
[https://webservices.amazon.com/**paapi5**/scratchpad/index.html](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/scratchpad/index.html)

Make the same request, and you should see all is ok